# Do we really need separate thumbnail images?

Tags: performance, ios7

I understand the use of thumbnail in network applications but assuming all the image are in the application itself (photo application), in this case do we still need thumbnail images for performance reasons or is it just fine for the device to resize the actual image on run time?

Since the question is too opinion based I am going to ask more quantitively.

- The images are 500x500, about 200-300kb size jpg.
- There will be about 200 images.
- It is targeted for iphone4 and higher, so that would be the minimum hardware specs users will have.
- The maximum memory used should not pass 20% of the devices capacity.

Will the application in this case need separate thumbnail images?

Comment: It depends. It take some CPU to adapt images. If you have a lot, I'd suggest to size them before.

Comment: have about 70 images, only 10 thumbnails will be on the screen at the same time in my case

Comment: 10 photos 2592 x 1936 stored in memory will require 200Mb of RAM. It is too much. You definitely have to use thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application. Just test performance and memory usage on device.

If you show a lot of images and/or they change very quickly (like when you are scrolling UITableView with a lot of images) you will probably have to use thumbnails.

UPDATE:

When image is shown it takes  `width * height * 3` (`width * height * 4` for images with ALPHA channel) bytes of memory. 10 photos 2592 x 1936 stored in memory will require 200Mb of RAM. It is too much. You definitely have to use thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit lacking on detail but I assume you're asking if, for say a photo album app, can you just throw around full size UIImages and let a UIImageView resize them to fit on the screen, or do you need to resize?

You absolutely need to resize.

An image taken by an iPhone camera will be several megabytes in compressed file size, more in actual bytes used to represent pixels. The dimensions of the image will be far greater than the screen dimensions of the device. The memory use is very high, particularly if you're thinking of showing multiple "thumbnails". It's not so much a CPU issue (once the image has been rendered it doesn't need re-rendering) but a memory one, and you're severely memory constrained on a mobile device.

Each doubling in size of an image (e.g. from a 100x100 to a 200x200) represents a four-fold increase in the memory needed to hold it.

Comment: thanks, what if they were edited versions of images and only take about 500-800kb of size?

Comment: The file size isn't really relevant due to JPEG compression and so forth. You need to think about the dimensions. Profile the memory usage to make sure, but basically any image held bigger than it is on the screen represents wasted memory. How _much_ wasted memory depends on the difference.